# Magento: What are the empty EAV setup classes for?

Tags: php, magento

There are lots of descendants of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` for example

```
class Mage_Checkout_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{
}
```

But all of them are empty.

What is the use of having all these empty classes?

Is it just for the sake of extensibiliy and to keep common functions that are shared in different setup scripts of the same module?

I was thinking there might be some kind of module autodetection triggered by these custom classes, but could not find any hints into this direction).

(Based on Magento Certification Study Guide: What are the advantages of using a custom setup class for manipulating EAV attributes in a custom module).

Comment: There is no point in empty setup model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to understand that Magento organizes it's code into modules.  The idea behind a module is to both help and **force** a developer to write their code in such a way that their code doesn't interfere with other system code.

Second, when a module needs to create persistant data in the Magento database, you create a [setup resource](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) (self-link).  A setup resource is an installer script that has access to special functions/methods via its parent class.  These special functions/methods help the developer create and populate tables in the database for their data structures.  Many of these methods can be found on the  `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` class.

When a developer creates a setup resource for their own module, **they create a new class**.  By creating a new class they ensure that any special methods their setup resources need will have a place to live.  The `Mage_Checkout_Model_Resource_Setup` class is the `Mage_Checkout` module's setup resource class.  It just so happens that this module didn't need extra methods. Earlier versions of Magento **forced** (at least, I believe they did) module developers to create their own setup resource classes if they wanted to use the setup resource feature.  This was done because, as mentioned in paragraph one, Magento's module system is there to help ensure code from Module A doesn't interfere with Module B.

Comment: But there are many cases where the methods of standard `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` class are sufficient and I do not need own methods. So I make my module dependent on Mage_Eav to ensure the setup class will be available. I think it is completely valid that code of module A interferes with module B, that is what dependencies are for.

Comment: @Alex In Magento "make my module dependent on" does not do what you think it does, likely.

Comment: @Alex Perfectly valid opinion, but it's clear the original Magneto system developers and current Magneto system maintainers have a different view of things — which is also perfectly valid.  Each has different tradeoffs.

Comment: @benmarks: Can you elaborate? As far as I know it causes the dependencies to be loaded earlier. So the setup class should be basically available.

Comment: @AlanStorm Okay, so it is more or less an opinion and style thing with only very few practical difference?

Comment: @Alex The `<depends>` node simply sets load order for module config.xml, nothing else. When classes are invoked, they are done so with all config XML merged. Any PHP-level relationships are handled via include path order and the autoloader.

Comment: @Alex — I'm not sure what you're driving at with your questions, but  for a day-to-day programmer no, there's not much practical difference. However, instead of thinking about the immediate needs of someone performing a specific task in Magento, think of a small group of programmers trying to build a system they want other disparate groups to contribute to.  With that mindset a lot of Magento's architecture choices/philosophy/systems start to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand the logic, you'll have to give [Alan Storm's tutorials](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) a read. Maybe you should read them in the proper order, but you can also jump straight to [this one](http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1). They definitely helped me understand what's going on a few years ago.